# A little "copy" button above each code block would be cool

Tags: feature-request

Often, I want to highlight & copy the contents of a single posted code block so I can paste it into my IDE for a better look or into my answer for editing. This gets awkward especially if there's scrolling involved -- I usually overshoot the end and trying to shift-arrow back into the code block just overshoots in the other direction.

Comment: This has already been requested on the [main meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/): [Shortcut for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow). Don't hold your breath…

Comment: Indeed. The feeling seems to be that the post has too much code if that was needed. Granted, CR has more code on average than most, but I'm not sure this will go anywhere if the old request has been active for over two years.

Comment: @Gilles Even I don't picture it being that useful on SO, but I miss it on CR.

Answer (score 5):

I agree, so I wrote a bookmarklet that puts a copy button on top of every code block.

It is going through Code Review now: [Bookmarklet for selecting code snippets on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/38336/14625)

Some excellent suggestions were made and it got turned into a CR repo :

http://codereviewcommunity.github.io/CodeReviewBookmarklet/

Comment: If I get around to finishing the indentation fixer (see http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/how-can-i-prepare-my-code-so-that-i-can-paste-it-formatted) would you be interested in merging it, rather than having another bookmarklet floating around separately?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely.

Comment: I don't care if I'm over 2 years late - thank you!